# Why does my OpenMP code with reduction give wrong results?

Tags: fortran, openmp, reduction

My Fortran code is as follows:

```
!     ...................... initialization

      do ia=1,NLEV
      do ic=1,NLEV
            ZGamma(ia,ic)  =zero
      enddo
      enddo

!$OMP PARALLEL DEFAULT(PRIVATE) SHARED(H,ZRO) REDUCTION(+: ZGamma)

!$OMP DO SCHEDULE(DYNAMIC) 

      do iabcd=1,H%iabcd_max
          ia = H%ka(iabcd)
          ib = H%kb(iabcd)
          ic = H%kc(iabcd)
          id = H%kd(iabcd)

          ZGamma(ia,ic)=ZGamma(ia,ic) + H%ME2BM(iabcd)*ZRO(id,ib)
          ZGamma(ib,ic)=ZGamma(ib,ic) - H%ME2BM(iabcd)*ZRO(id,ia)
          ZGamma(ia,id)=ZGamma(ia,id) - H%ME2BM(iabcd)*ZRO(ic,ib)
          ZGamma(ib,id)=ZGamma(ib,id) + H%ME2BM(iabcd)*ZRO(ic,ia)

          if(ia+ib.eq.ic+id) cycle
          ZGamma(ic,ia)=ZGamma(ic,ia) + H%ME2BM(iabcd)*ZRO(ib,id)
          ZGamma(id,ia)=ZGamma(id,ia) - H%ME2BM(iabcd)*ZRO(ib,ic)

          ZGamma(ic,ib)=ZGamma(ic,ib) - H%ME2BM(iabcd)*ZRO(ia,id)
          ZGamma(id,ib)=ZGamma(id,ib) + H%ME2BM(iabcd)*ZRO(ia,ic)

       enddo ! iabcd
!$OMP END DO

!$OMP END PARALLEL
```

In the above code, I calculated the 2D array `ZGamma(i,j)` using OpenMP. Even though I can compile the code without any problem. Could anyone tell me what the problem is in the code? What changes should I make?

By the way, as the index "iabcd" running from "1" to "H%iabcd_max", the values of "(ia,ib,ic,id)" can be "(1,1,1,1),(1,1,1,2),(1,1,1,...), (1,1,2,1),(1,1,2,..)," etc.

Comment: How do you assess the validity of the results?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Shouldn't the reduction clause take care of that?

Comment: In H%ka(:) are all the values unique? i.e. are any numbers repeated? And similarly for H%k[bcd](:)?

Comment: The values in H%ka() are not unique, but the combination of ia,ib,ic,id is unique.

Comment: The code stoped with the message "line 35: 45393 Segmentation fault      (core dumped)"

Comment: Now I guess the problem is due to the shortage of memory. H%iabcd_max=282907560. H%ka,kb,kc,kd takes memory: 4.216G byte H%ME2B takes memory:2.108 G byte.

Comment: You have to show more if you want a definitive answer, see [mcve]. It is good to know how the variables are declared. If you think the memory is insufficient you can try to run your code *without* OpenMP. Honestly, it is the first thing you should try. Also, do not put important information into comments, edit the question and put it there.

Comment: Sorry, now I am confused. Is the code giving the wrong answer as per the title, or is it failing with a segmentation fault as per the comment.

Comment: "but the combination of ia,ib,ic,id is unique" That's not a strong enough condition to avoid a race. If for one iteration ia=ic=1 and id=2 and for another ia=id=1 and ic=2 the first and third lines of updates could result in the same element being added to by different threads at the same time.

Comment: Actually, I am not sure if the problem was caused by storage of memory. I also received the message: *** longjmp causes uninitialized stack frame ***: ./run terminated
*** longjmp causes uninitialized stack frame ***: ./run terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x721af)[0x2adccff7c1af]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x37)[0x2adcd0003f37]

Comment: But I tried to remove "REDUCTION(+: ZGamma)" and add "ZGamma" into the "SHARED(H,ZRO, Zgamma)". The code could run through, but the results were different from those without using the OpenMP.

Comment: "If for one iteration ia=ic=1 and id=2 and for another ia=id=1 and ic=2 the first and third lines of updates could result in the same element being added to by different threads at the same time." Yes, you are right. For this case, what should I do? If there any way to avoid this problem? Before, I thought the use of "REDUCTION"  for "ZGamma" can avoid it.

Comment: This is way, WAY, too chaotic. Too many versions of the code, different errors or results...  [edit] your question with a structured sequence of 1. **code**, 2. **output**, 3. explanation of **what is wrong** about the output.  Otherwise an answer is impossible.